# Source of datetime formats, decimal separators for all countries

Tags: localization, locale

Does anyone know free source of datetime formats, decimal separators, native months and days names which could be used in desktop apps? Some kind of XML or JSON description. For example, user want de_DE locale where default datetime format should be: "DD.MM.YY HH:MM" for short and "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS" for long. For other locale it could be "DD/MM/YY HH:MM". Same for currency, date separator, decimal separator, 12/24 hour clock etc. My destination platform is Free Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Not XML or JSON, but you could try using [ICU4PAS](http://crossgl.com/icu4pas/), a Pascal wrapper around the ICU library. Check the [documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) for the date/time formatting options that you can get from ICU. It seems that ICU4PAS is no longer actively maintained, but perhaps it does what you need.